# AWS lambda sequential execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, execution

I've been working on a Lambda function but the test for it is failing because it is no longer executing sequentially-but was yesterday.

Is there any way to enforce sequential execution?

Comment: Lambda is fundamentally stateless and parallel. If you need to process things sequentially, each to completion before the next starts, then consider a FIFO SQS queue or Step Functions.

Comment: Giving a bit more detail may help answer your question, e.g. what language are you using, maybe post some or all of your code (removing anything sensitive like keys)

Answer (score 1):

Just had to use Javascript promises to get it to run the functions in the order I want. Don't know why it only started being a problem part way through.